# how to respond to ARP messages using floodlight controller API

Tags: java, controller, arp, sdn

I want to respond the ARP packets sent to the controller with the correct mac address of the requested machine.
To build the ARP cache in PC1, PC2 and PC3, but I don't know how to make this using the floodlight apis (I already know how to add a module to the floodlight controller).

So my question is how can I change the ARP Broadcast mac ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  with the correct MAC address and return it as ARP replay packet using the correct port number to the machine that asked for the mac ?
For example in the next diagram, at the beginning of communication PC1 can't know what's the mac address of PC2 so the ovs-switch will send openflow message 
to the controller containing ARP messages and I don't know how to deal with them ?

```
           ┌───────────────┐
      ┌────┤   Controller  ├────┐
      │    └────┬──────────┘    │
      │         │               │
      │         │               │
    ┌─┴─┐       │             ┌─┴─┐
    │PC1╞╗eth1  │        eth1╔╡PC2│
    └───┘║      │            ║└───┘
         ║      │            ║
         ║    ┌─┴─┐          ║
         ╚════╡PC3╞══════════╝
          eth2└───┘eth1
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Are you asking how to change the destination MAC address of a packet using the Controller?

Comment: i want to store an ARP - IP couples in a table in the controller side and make a floodlight module that handle the ARP requests , the module must return the correct ARP address to the switch (bridge), i need this feature to make multiple routing decisions in a network that have loops without using STP, at this moment it's working by putting ARP addresses manually with my flow rules.